# JavaScript works just once

Tags: javascript

I have the following script. It works when the users clicks the search button but it only works once. Please guide me how can I make it work for more clicks. Thanks,

```
 <form action="" method="get" id="searchform">
   <input name="q" type="text" id="search" size="32" maxlength="128" class="txt">
   <input type="button" id="hit" value="Search"  class="btn">
 </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var nexturl ="";
  var lastid ="";
  var param;
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#hit").on("click", function myFunction() {
      param = $('#search').val();
      alert("I am an alert box!");
      if (param != "") {
        $("#status").show();
        var u = 'https://graph.facebook.com/search/?callback=&limit=100&q='+param;
        getResults(u);
      }

      $("#more").click(function () { 
        $("#status").show();
        $("#more").hide();  
        pageTracker._trackPageview('/?q=/more');
        var u = nexturl;
        getResults(u);
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of... I'm not even going to search it this has been answered so many times.

Comment: @AustinMullins:I tried to bind it by click but that solution dint worked(I have read those answers).

Comment: works all times here
http://jsfiddle.net/VsHyP/

Comment: You're not dynamically adding elements, so why use .on()?

Comment: @Terry It's the button in the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this has been asked many times before, but here it is:

```
$(document).on("click", "#hit", function() {
  ...
});
```

You need to let the event bubble up to the document so changes to the DOM don't wipe out your event handling.

Here it is in [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/KzmN4/). Let me know what you're seeing.

Comment: I'm not sure specifying a container element is required in this scenario, he's not dynamically adding elements to the DOM and binding events to them.

Comment: I don't understand why you're naming the function in the `.on` block. I don't know if that causes any errors, but that name is getting wiped out every time.

Comment: The search results gets displayed the first time but not after that

Comment: I see it now. It's nice to know what the problem actually is.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not actually submitting the form and just running JavaScript, you should be running it as an onsubmit on the form instead like so:

```
<form id="searchform" onsubmit='return submitForm()'>
  <input name="q" type="text" id="search" size="32" maxlength="128" class="txt"  >
  <input type="button" id="hit" value="Search"  class="btn">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var nexturl ="";

  function submitForm(){
    var lastid ="";
    var param = $('#search').val();

    alert("I am an alert box!");
    if (param != "") {
      $("#status").show();
      var u = 'https://graph.facebook.com/search/?callback=&limit=100&q='+param;
      getResults(u);
    }

    //Prevents the form submitting
    return false;
  }

  $("#more").click(function () { 
    $("#status").show();
    $("#more").hide();  
    pageTracker._trackPageview('/?q=/more');
    var u = nexturl;
    getResults(u);
  });
</script>
```

Does the more button always exist or is it something that's dynamically added/removed? If so, you will probably need to do something like

```
$("body").on("click", "#more", function () { 
  $("#status").show();
  $("#more").hide();  
  pageTracker._trackPageview('/?q=/more');
  var u = nexturl;
  getResults(u);
});
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I couldn't see where the error was.

Answer (score 1):

It also works on the second search. The Items of the second search just get appended to the list of search results, maybe thats why you dont see them. Try an $("#data").empty(); before you start appending results of a new search query.