# jQuery.on('click', 'element', function) simplifying doesn't work

Tags: jquery, onclicklistener, jquery-events, simplify

I'm trying to make my jQuery code simpler - `.on('click', function)`, I usually replace by `.click(function)` and things like that. However, I have a code looking like this:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#lightbox', function() {
    //do something
});
```

And I don't really understand the structure. I've tried reading on it on jQuery.com and such, but it's explained in a complicated way. My problem is, why isn't that line looking like this..:

```
jQuery('#lightbox').on('click', function() {
    //do something
});
```

... so that I could simplify it to this?:

```
jQuery('#lightbox').click(function() {
    //do something
});
```

When I try that, it won't work. Why is the selector `document` instead of the actual element (`'#lightbox'`) to be clicked, and then it's referenced later in another argument?

Can anyone explain this to me? Just a simple question - I'm not an expert in jQuery (as you may have understood by now), and this isn't a major error either, it's just bugging me a little that I can't have the same `click` code everywhere (because the simplified code works other places).

(I can upload the whole code and make a Fiddle if necessary, it's only 70 lines, so should be easy)

Comment: try to put click inside of $(document).ready(function(){});

Comment: `jQuery('#lightbox').click` is not the way to simplify `jQuery(document).on('click', '#lightbox',`, they are totally different, the first is ***static*** binding and the second is ***dynamic*** binding, that means at the time of binding, the `#lightbox` should exist so that the binding is successful for the first way, however it does not need to be existent at the time of binding using the second way, after that if it's added to the DOM, it will be successfully bound to the event handler. The second way is also called event delegating.

Comment: I doubt that you create the `#lightbox` dynamically, that why after trying to *simplify* the code by `jQuery('#lightbox').click`, it does not work. Also the documentation in jQuery homepage is clear enough about the 2 different ways of using `.on()`.

Comment: _"it's just bugging me a little that I can't have the same click code everywhere"_ - You can't have the same click code everywhere for the same reason you can't replace those lines with a `$.guessWhatIMean()` function. When you pass different arguments to a function it behaves differently. `.on()` accepts several different types of arguments, and it behaves different for each, so obviously you can't just replace all cases of `.on('click'...)` with the more generic `.click()`.

Comment: @nnnnnn Hahah, I know that I can't replace it all with `$.guessWhatIMean()`, unfortunately, I must say. However, as a less advanced user than you, I don't think a simple thing as clicking should be that complicated - so, in my opinion, both codes should just work, dynamically created or not.

Comment: Yes, the creators of jQuery _could_ have chosen to make `.click()` (and other event shortcut methods like `.blur()`) accept extra arguments like `.on()` does. But like it or not they didn't. As an aside, note that delegated event handlers as in your first example have more uses than just handling events on dynamically created elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use this :

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#lightbox', function() {
    //do something
});
```

only if `#lightbox` element is loaded after the event listener was set (e.g: if you create the `#lightbox` element using AJAX after the page was loaded).

If `#lightbox` exist from the start on your page, then use this :

```
jQuery("#lightbox").click(function() {
    //do something
});
```

As charlietfl said : *Note that `click()` is just a shorthand for `on('click')`*

Comment: also note that `click()` is just a shorthand for `on('click')` since that was what was being discussed in question

Comment: oh that was the point ? ok, i'll add it to the answer then, thanks

Comment: I just threw it in , in case there was any confusion. Both will work is my point since `click()` actually ends up going through `on()` internally

Comment: Thanks for all the comments on this - it's true that the element is created dynamically some lines above this code, and obviously, I didn't know that the element had to be existent from before to use the latter, thanks all for enlightening me.

Answer (score 1):

As @Oliboy50 pointed out, you need the delegating version of `.on` in order to dynamically add handlers for objects that don't exist yet in the DOM. For an example of this case, check out [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/bfNXA/).

What's happening with `$(document).on(event, selector, func)` is that events not handled by the elements that raise them (like the `click` event on the `#ligthbox` element) bubble up to the main `document` node. (Actually, they bubble up anyway, thanks @nnnnnn for the reminder). At this point, jQuery checks to see if the source of the event matches the selector from the call to `.on`, if it does, it calls `func` and passes in an event object.

For more information, read [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Related questions:

- [Submitting a form with jQuery/Ajax only works every other time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741746/submitting-a-form-with-jquery-ajax-only-works-every-other-time)
- [JavaScript works just once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172823/javascript-works-just-once)

Comment: _"events not handled by the elements that raise them...bubble up"_ - Note that events bubble even if they have been handled lower down, unless the lower-level handler deliberately prevents propagation...